# Why the axis I generated using d3js is significantly different from the example even though the code are similar?

Tags: d3.js

I've just started learning D3 for 2 month and when I try to apply it on a project to generate some chart, I found the axis I generated is significantly different from the one from most of the examples.

Instead of an elegant thin axis with clear ticks as those in the examples, it appears to be an ugly huge black bar.
Here is my code relative to the axis:

```
var scale_x = d3.time.scale().range([0,width-40]).domain(d3.extent(nested, function(d){return d.key;})),
    scale_y = d3.scale.linear().range([height-40,0]).domain([0,d3.max(nested, function(d){return d.values})]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(scale_x).orient("bottom").ticks(10),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(scale_y).orient("left").ticks(10);

var chartLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d){return scale_x(d.key)})
    .y(function(d){return scale_y(d.values)});

chart_container.append("g")
    .attr("class","x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,560)")
    .call(xAxis)

chart_container.append("g")
    .attr("class","y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("frequency");
```

And it result is like this:

[image]

, you can compare with one of the many examples like [mbostock’s block #7621155: Natural Log Scale](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7621155).

So could anyone tell me if there is some hidden mechanism in d3.js that decides how the axis should be look like?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hidden mechanism is the CSS :)

Add these to your CSS

```
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.axis--x text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis--y text {
  font: oblique 15px Georgia, serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

Hope this helps!